# re-render not behaving properly

Tags: reactjs

So I deployed the app to demonstrate the problem
https://ecstatic-mayer-aaa530.netlify.app/
When you 'refresh' the page new data is fetched and user name is displayed (along with active state)
BUT when I click random user button, I don't get the same behavior even though I refetch the data. I want to get the same behavior as page refresh. (Name is displayed with the active state)
**To better observe the problem you can : Hover on other fields, click on random user btn and then re-enter with your mouse on name (profile icon). *It is not updating as you'll see***

```
import './App.css';
import ProfileCard from './components/ProfileCard';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
    const [triggerFetch, setTriggerFetch] = useState(false);

    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/');
        const data = await response.json();
        setUserData(setFields(data.results[0]));
    };

    const setFields = (userData) => {
        const fName = userData.name.first;
        const lName = userData.name.last;
        const fullName = fName + ' ' + lName;
        return {
            image: userData.picture.large,
            name: fullName,
            email: userData.email,
            dob: userData.dob.date,
            location: userData.location.street.name,
            phone: userData.phone,
            password: userData.login.password,
        };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [triggerFetch]);

    //this triggers fetch
    const handleRandomUserClick = () => {
        setTriggerFetch(!triggerFetch);
    };

    return (
        <main>
            <div className='grey-bg'></div>

            <ProfileCard
                userData={userData}
                handleRandomUserClick={handleRandomUserClick}
            />
        </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
   import React from 'react';
   import {
       FaUserAlt,
       FaPhoneAlt,
       FaBirthdayCake,
       FaLock,
       FaLocationArrow,
       FaEnvelope,
   } from 'react-icons/fa';
   
   const ProfileCard = ({ userData, handleRandomUserClick }) => {
       const { image, name, email, dob, location, phone, password } = userData;
   
       const [randomUserClicked, setrandomUserClicked] = React.useState(false);
   
       const defaultFlag = {
           name: 'active',
           email: '',
           dob: '',
           location: '',
           phone: '',
           password: '',
       };
   
       const [flag, setFlag] = React.useState(defaultFlag);
       const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('My Name Is');
       const [value, setValue] = React.useState(name);
   
       const handleValue = (e) => {
           if (e.target.dataset.label === 'name') {
               setTitle('My Name is');
               setValue(name);
               setFlag(defaultFlag);
           } else if (e.target.dataset.label === 'email') {
               setTitle('My Email is');
               setValue(email);
               setFlag({
                   name: '',
                   email: 'active',
                   dob: '',
                   location: '',
                   phone: '',
                   password: '',
               });
           } else if (e.target.dataset.label === 'dob') {
               setTitle('My Birthday is');
               setValue(new Date(dob).toLocaleDateString());
               setFlag({
                   name: '',
                   email: '',
                   dob: 'active',
                   location: '',
                   phone: '',
                   password: '',
               });
           } else if (e.target.dataset.label === 'location') {
               setTitle('I live in');
               setValue(location);
               setFlag({
                   name: '',
                   email: '',
                   dob: '',
                   location: 'active',
                   phone: '',
                   password: '',
               });
           } else if (e.target.dataset.label === 'phone') {
               setTitle('My phone number is');
               setValue(phone);
               setFlag({
                   name: '',
                   email: '',
                   dob: '',
                   location: '',
                   phone: 'active',
                   password: '',
               });
           } else {
               setTitle('My password');
               setValue(password);
               setFlag({
                   name: '',
                   email: '',
                   dob: '',
                   location: '',
                   phone: '',
                   password: 'active',
               });
           }
   
           if (e.target.dataset.label === 'random') {
               handleRandomUserClick();
               setrandomUserClicked(!randomUserClicked);
           }
       };
   
       React.useEffect(() => {
           setTitle('My Name is');
           setValue(name);
           setFlag(defaultFlag);
       }, [randomUserClicked]);
   
       return (
           <article className='profile-card'>
               <img src={image} alt={name} />
   
               <div className='user-details'>
                   <p className='user-title'>{title}</p>
                   <h3 className='user-value'>{value || name}</h3>
               </div>
   
               <ul className='card-list'>
                   <li className={flag.name} onMouseEnter={handleValue} data-label='name'>
                       <FaUserAlt className='icon' />
                   </li>
                   <li
                       data-label='email'
                       onMouseEnter={handleValue}
                       className={flag.email}
                   >
                       <FaEnvelope className='icon' />
                   </li>
                   <li data-label='dob' onMouseEnter={handleValue} className={flag.dob}>
                       <FaBirthdayCake className='icon' />
                   </li>
                   <li
                       data-label='location'
                       onMouseEnter={handleValue}
                       className={flag.location}
                   >
                       <FaLocationArrow className='icon' />
                   </li>
                   <li
                       data-label='phone'
                       onMouseEnter={handleValue}
                       className={flag.phone}
                   >
                       <FaPhoneAlt className='icon' />
                   </li>
                   <li
                       data-label='password'
                       onMouseEnter={handleValue}
                       className={flag.password}
                   >
                       <FaLock className='icon' />
                   </li>
               </ul>
               {/* Also handling this click within handleValue function */}
               <button className='btn' onClick={handleValue} data-label='random'>
                   Random User
               </button>
           </article>
       );
   };
   
   export default ProfileCard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens, because in `ProfileCard` component, `userData` is not listed under `useEffects`'s dependencies array.

---

By the way, your component design is very prone to bugs. In React functional components should be a simple functions that receive some data (props) and return JSX. Hooks should be used only when you actually have to use them. In your app, you're creating a complicated network of effects, state updates and re-renders, which makes it hard to maintain.

Let's write all hooks you actually need:

- one state for the data fetched from an api
- one state for keeping which section is currently active (name, email, etc.)
- one effect for fetching the data

And that's it! Everything else can be just passed through props.

Comment: Much appreciated but I'm fetching the data -> destructuring it -> passing it down to ProfileCard -> and making operations within ProfileCard. what part is not 'react way' ?

Comment: I understand your point however wouldn't that 'bloat' App component ? What's wrong with dealing with state-related operations WITHIN a specific component ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add more detail